# ChaiJS doesn't handle exceptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

Here is a NodeJS module:

```
var plural = function(words, num) {
    if (words.length != 3) {
        throw new Error('Wrong words array');
    }
    var lastNum = num % 10;
    var second = (num / 10) % 10;
    if (second == 1)
        return words[2]
    else if (lastNum == 1)
        return words[0];
    else if (lastNum <= 4)
        return words[1];
    else
        return words[2];
};

module.exports = plural;
```

And here is module test:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var plural = require('../plural')

describe('Test with wrong array', function() {

    it('Must throw Error', function() {
        expect(plural(['я','меня'])).to.throw(Error);
    });

});
```

I want to test exception throwing. But this is `mocha`'s  output:

```
 Test with wrong array
   1) Must throw Error

 1 failing

 1) Test with wrong array Must throw Error:
    Error: Wrong words array
     at plural (C:\Users\home\Google Drive\Учеба\Спецкурсы\Яндекс.Интерфейсы\TestableCode\testable-code-01\plural.js:3:9)
     at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Users\home\Google Drive\Учеба\Спецкурсы\Яндекс.Интерфейсы\TestableCode\testable-code-01\test\cat.test.js:31:10)
     at callFn (C:\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:250:21)
     at Test.Runnable.run (C:\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:243:7)
     at Runner.runTest (C:\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:373:10)
     at C:\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:451:12
     at next (C:\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:298:14)
     at C:\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:308:7
     at next (C:\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:246:23)
     at Object._onImmediate (C:\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:275:5)
     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:345:15)
```

So, my code throws exceptions, which is right behavior, and test should be passed. But is doesn't. What's the problem?

Comment: You have to pass a function to expect() by reference - see my updated answer below and [test cases](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/test/expect.js#L676)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chai's to.throw() method is shorthand for an [assertThrows](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/core/assertions.js#L1033) method which expects a couple of arguments to be passed to it. You can see an example of to.throw() [here](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/test/assert.js#L20). It looks like throws() needs to be passed the constructor of the Error you will throw.

You can see the definition of AssertionError in Chai's seperate library 'assertion-error' [here](https://github.com/chaijs/assertion-error/blob/master/index.js) if you are interested in throwing a custom error message.

In your case, you should be able to pass in `Error.constructor` or `Error` I would imagine to achieve the same effect.

```
expect(plural(['я','меня'])).to.throw(Error);
```

Also, you have to pass the function to expect by reference - you are *executing* the function before it gets to be used as an argument to expect:

```
expect(function(){
   plural(['я','меня']);
}).to.throw(Error);
```

Comment: the test fails either with `expect(plural(['я','меня'])).to.throw(Error.constructor);`

Comment: Essentially, the last step you need to do is find out what the constructor of your Error function is. When you call 'throw new Error()' it should just use Error as it's constructor - you aren't redefining the Error global anywhere are you?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the line:

```
expect(plural(['я','меня'])).to.throw();
```

Should read

```
expect(plural(['я','меня'])).to.throw(Error);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I just replace your `expect(plural...` line with

```
expect(plural.bind(undefined, ['я','меня'])).to.throw(Error);
```

then it works.

As netpoetica explained, you can't just put `plural(...)` inside `expect` because then `plural` is called *before* `expect` executes and what `expect` gets is the *return value* of `plural` but because it throws an exception, `expect` does not get to execute. Also, what `expect` wants is a function that *it* will call to check whether or not it throws an exception. netpoetica used an anonymous function to do that. I prefer to use `bind`. What `bind` does in the code above is create a new function from `plural` which when called will have the value of `this` set to `undefined` and the first parameter set to `['я','меня']`.